# Wordpress remove capability post ,media completely for custom role

Tags: capabilities, user-roles

I have created a new role .Now I want to remove **post** ,**media**, **setting** capability for that role.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is your new role name?

Comment: do you think: post, media, settings are capabilities?

Answer (score 1):

Remove a top level admin menu:

```
    function custom_menu_page_removing() {
    remove_menu_page( $menu_slug );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'custom_menu_page_removing' );
```

To remove only certain menu items include only those you want to hide within the function. 
To remove menus for only certain users you may want to utilize current_user_can().

You can take a look at https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page

Answer (score 0):

Would you be so kind to try this:

```
$data = get_userdata( 1 ); // or any other ID where your new role works
if ( !empty( $data) ) {
    $user_caps = $data->allcaps;
    echo '<pre>' . print_r( $user_caps, true ) . '</pre>';
}
```

You will get the idea of capabilities on your end.

```
Array
(
    [switch_themes] => 1
    [edit_themes] => 1
    [activate_plugins] => 1
    [edit_plugins] => 1
    [edit_users] => 1
    [edit_files] => 1
    [manage_options] => 1
    [moderate_comments] => 1
    [manage_categories] => 1
    [manage_links] => 1
    [upload_files] => 1
    [import] => 1
    [unfiltered_html] => 1
    [edit_posts] => 1
    [edit_others_posts] => 1
    [edit_published_posts] => 1
    [publish_posts] => 1
    [edit_pages] => 1
    [read] => 1
    [level_10] => 1
    [level_9] => 1
    [level_8] => 1
    [level_7] => 1
    [level_6] => 1
    [level_5] => 1
    [level_4] => 1
    [level_3] => 1
    [level_2] => 1
    [level_1] => 1
    [level_0] => 1
    [edit_others_pages] => 1
    [edit_published_pages] => 1
    [publish_pages] => 1
    [delete_pages] => 1
    [delete_others_pages] => 1
    [delete_published_pages] => 1
    [delete_posts] => 1
    [delete_others_posts] => 1
    [delete_published_posts] => 1
    [delete_private_posts] => 1
    [edit_private_posts] => 1
    [read_private_posts] => 1
    [delete_private_pages] => 1
    [edit_private_pages] => 1
    [read_private_pages] => 1
    [delete_users] => 1
    [create_users] => 1
    [unfiltered_upload] => 1
    [edit_dashboard] => 1
    [update_plugins] => 1
    [delete_plugins] => 1
    [install_plugins] => 1
    [update_themes] => 1
    [install_themes] => 1
    [update_core] => 1
    [list_users] => 1
    [remove_users] => 1
    [promote_users] => 1
    [edit_theme_options] => 1
    [delete_themes] => 1
    [export] => 1
    [view_query_monitor] => 1
    [administrator] => 1
)
```

Then remove them simple with this code:

```
// Remove a capability from a specific user.
$user_id = // The ID of the user to remove the capability from.
$user = new WP_User( $user_id );
$user->remove_cap( 'read_private_posts' );
```

from [ref](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_cap).